# Chrome Extension not detecting notification permission

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, html5-notifications

I'm using the [Chrome Extension Example Tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) to build a simple extension to display a HTML5 desktop notification.

The trouble I seem to be having is that although I have changed the manifest file to request notification permission (See Below) but when I check permission none have been requested.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Desktop notification",
  "description": "Show a desktop notification",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

If I change the permissions back to the original permission it works fine.

Comment: Did you reload the extension after you made the change?

Comment: Yes, even tried restarting the browser

Comment: How did you check the requested permissions ?

Comment: In extensions in chrome I click on the permissions link

Comment: @jampez77 were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notifications` permission is not considered "special" enough to be listed in the requested permissions of the extension. Not being listed there does not mean it not "granted" to the extension.